# Ionic app crashing with HTTP GET inside of another HTTP GET

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4.  In order to get around CORS, I'm using this plugin - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

I make a call:

```
newurl = '<some google api url>';
this.http.get(newurl, {}, {}).then(data => {
      newurl = '<some other google api url>'
      this.http.get(newurl, {}, {}).then(data2 => {  //<=== this one fails

      }
}
```

The second GET call is failing.  Because the plugin is Cordova, I have to run it on my device (cant use ionic serve), and I dont have any logs - the Sentry logging service isn't sending anything to me.

I know before I upgraded to Ionic 4 and was using the old Http Module, I could chain calls like this - can you not do this now?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any console errors? Try to catch if there is an error in the promise

Comment: I cannot debug in the browser because its a Cordova plugin, so I do not have access to the console.  I have a logging service (Sentry), but it is not providing any info.

Comment: No. You can still debug it if you aren't using a production version. You can check it here: https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2

Comment: Ok, I tried this as well, and it is not providing anything to the Console - it just crashes hard with no info.  I log to the console right up to the point of the second http.get, and then - nothing.

Comment: Did you try to catch the error? `this.http.get(newurl, {}, {}).then(data2 => { }, error => alert(error))`

Comment: I figured out what was going on - there were conflicting Cordova plugins that had different versions of Ok HTTP - so after lining those up, everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on - there were conflicting Cordova plugins that had different versions of Ok HTTP - so after lining those up, everything worked